# ASP.NET Core 1 RC2 add reference to "Microsoft.Data.SqlXml"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core-rc2

I created a MVC 6 project with RC1 and added reference to "Microsoft.Data.SqlXml" with no problem. When I migrated to RC2, I can not add the reference to "Microsoft.Data.SqlXml". I get an error message ".Net Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release. To reference other assemblies, they need to be included in a NuGet package and reference that package." Is there a easy way I can add the reference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finally able to add the reference "Microsoft.Data.SqlXml" by creating NuGet package, to the project migrated to RC2.

1. Publish RC1 project to file system and find out the package folder "Microsoft.Data.SqlXml" under "PublishOutput"
2. Download [Nuget Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) and open the .nuspec file in "Microsoft.Data.SqlXml" package folder.
3. Edit the files .nuspec, project.json, project.lock.json in Nuget Package Explorer, change all words "DNX" -> ".NETFramework", and "Save As" package file Microsoft.Data.SqlXml.nupkg.
4. In VS 2015, Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Setting, add local folder to package source list, then copy the .nupkg file to the folder
5. Install the Microsoft.Data.SqlXml NuGet package from the local source

I don't know why MS made the thing so complicated, 2 seconds work in RC1 but took me one day to figure it out in RC2.